# How to save URL images to a gallery in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have an array of images coming from sever. I have a button to save it to gallery. The images coming from server are in url form. Now i want to download the image which i select from an array. I have a button when then image opens in larger view, but the code is used is not working. 
Code,

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"property_images"];
NSLog(@"GGG %@",arrayOfImages);


self.imagesData=[[NSArray alloc]init];
self.imagesData = arrayOfImages;

NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];


for (UIImageView *imageViewToSave in self.imagesData){


    NSInteger tag = imageViewToSave.tag;
    UIImage *image = imageViewToSave.image;
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%li.png",(long)tag];

    NSString *imagePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    // Log the image and path being saved.  If either of these are nil, nothing will be written.
    NSLog(@"Saving %@ to %@", image, imagePath);

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
}
NSLog(@"Save Button Pressed");
```

This is how we can show image on tap gesture,

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"property_images"];
NSLog(@"GGG %@",arrayOfImages);

self.imagesData=[[NSArray alloc]init];
self.imagesData = arrayOfImages;
NSLog(@"Image Array is %@",_imagesData);
//dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
for(int i=0; i<self.imagesData.count;i++){

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]]
placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch.png"]];

    // imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandImage:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    imageView.tag = i;
    NSLog(@"KK %ld",imageView.tag);
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

   // dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        //dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    _fullImage.hidden=NO;
    _fullView.hidden=NO;
}
```

The method for expand is this,

```
 -(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
{
    //  _fullImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:recogniser.view.tag]];




    [_fullImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:recogniser.view.tag]]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch.png"]];
    NSLog(@"RRR %@",self.imagesData);
    NSLog(@"TTT %ld",recogniser.view.tag);

    }
```

Comment: your code save image in document directory not gallary.

Comment: How can i save that in gallery? @Dixit Akabari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this function:**

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                               id completionTarget, 
                               SEL completionSelector, 
                               void *contextInfo);
```

**completionTarget**, **completionSelector** and **contextInfo** all notified when the UIImage is done saving if not use this all then you can pass nil.

**like.**

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(your UIImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Bro how can i pass the selected image to ur code? @Dixit Akabari

Comment: check it now bro. @Dixit Akabari

Comment: what you want exactly? tell me please.

Comment: my senario is that, i have a slider in which the images comes in an array from server, when i tap on any image in s slider it open that image in a big view with its specific tag, In that view i have a save button , now i want that when i hit the save button it should save that image in photolibrary. @Dixit Akabari

Comment: @Raheel you show display large image inside bigview? if yes then button click put above code and get image from uiimageview.

Comment: How can i only save that image which i have in bigview? Where to pass my image url in ur code so that image could save? @Dixit Akabari

Comment: @Raheel like.  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([YourUIImageView image], nil, nil, nil);

Comment: @Raheel Ok. happy to help you.

Comment: Bro , i have to test it on real device? @Dixit Akabari

Comment: how we can check it that its save in photo library in simulator? @Dixit Akabari

Comment: @Raheel simple open photos application.

Comment: it is not there i check it in simulator. @Dixit Akabari

Comment: @Raheel debugging  and check you pass uiimage in above code because this code i have use its working.

Comment: i have pass my property of uiimageview.image to it. I have used break points its green, but it is not saving the image. @Dixit Akabari